# No empty value in XSLTForms/XForms Select1 (drop list mode) control

Tags: xforms, xsltforms

I'm new with XForms and I'm wondering how to specify a [Select1 control](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Select1_drop_list) has no blank option, so I need to take one of the values in the list, but never a blank option, because the behaviour of some controls depends of that value.

[image]

I was reading [the spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/wiki/XForms_2.0#ui-selectOne), but I coudn't find the way to do it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLTForms is using HTML4 select element for rendering XForms select1 control.

When no option is selected yet, I am afraid this the only way with just HTML4.

--Alain

Comment: Alain: I mean, the control is generated with a blank option, like this one:
<option value="&nbsp;">&nbsp;</option>
And that's what I wanna avoid

Comment: Well, the blank option is required as long as no option is selected yet. After that, it is removed.